# Package for writing web service documentation

Tags: packages

Does exist some packages to define web service documentation?

I have a RESTful web service. I used [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) to create some documentation in yaml.

Now I want to expose my api to external developer and to explain of it works.

Does exist a package that add some "environment" for web service documentation or that read and visualize yaml?

I'm looking for something like Swagger representation, like in this example: [example](https://petstore.swagger.io/?_ga=2.72353872.2128187951.1594734219-1893407157.1587733858#/pet/updatePetWithForm)

Something like:

```
\begin{environment}
   method=post
   url=http://mysite/pet/{id}
   header{name=Authorization,value=AAAA}
\end{environment}
```

and magically something formatted appears.

For the response I could use a `\begin{lstlisting}[language=json]` with some customizations like in the example.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=json]
{
"access_token": "eyJhJSUzI1...WVrn.eyJleEOTQc...VzZXoidXRlbnRlIn.Zm...WsCWg",
"expires_in": 600,
"refresh_expires_in": 1800,
"refresh_token": "eyJhbG...fQ.eyJleHAiOjE...wifQ.cXW09GD...SXY",
"token_type": "bearer",
"not-before-policy": 1586965065,
"session_state": "e0fab4a9-a374-44e0-9315-75816f19f1e6",
"scope": "profile email"
}  
\end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not familiar with Swagger nor yaml.  The usual packages for source code are listings and minted.  Would they work for your purposes?  If not, what does your documentation look like, and what would you like the output to look like?

Comment: @Teepeemm Hi! I use listings for yaml, json or source-code. I'll add an example how i would see my api

Comment: So you want the environment with method, url, and header in your source code, and you'd like the output of that lstlisting in your pdf?  Is that correct?  I'm not seeing how the two are connected.  You should be able to use TikZ (and possibly tcolorbox) to get something resembling that Swagger html.